# wix PersonalFolder issue

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am new to wix (Windows Installer XML) so I folloed some tutorials like [this one](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started) 
but what I need is that the application will be installed in the user personal folder so I replaced ProgramFilesFolder by PersonalFolder in the code. but Ive got this error:

```
Error   1   ICE38: Component MainExecutable installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file. C:\Proxym-IT\Projets Visual Studio\SetupProject2\SetupProject2\Product.wxs  18  1   SetupProject2
```

any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just had the same issue. found the solution (the right one, without disabling the warning):

```
<Component Id="CCCCCC" Guid="120A49C6-3DB7-467F-A515-0DE9772F3B67" Win64="yes" Directory="LOCALAPPDATA">
            <RegistryValue KeyPath="yes" Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\ACME\Icecream" Name="Installed" Type="integer" Value="1" Action="write" />
            <File Id="F_TeaShellconfig" Name="Icecream.config" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAppData" On="uninstall" />
        </Component>
```

in fact, one has to add a dummy reg key to make this work. as someone said, the windows installer developers are presumably from another planet. the RemoveFolder tag below removes the next error I had, it is not related to the solution here, but it often goes together with it.